# Need Savings totals by month to pull data correctly and display in Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

My data and this SSRS chart have a ton of problems, I'll try to keep my question(s) succinct.

First, as you can see by this chart and this screenshot of my data (just showing date and April Savings), my expression/chart is not summing all of the savings within a month, which is my goal.

[image: screenshot1]

It appears to be picking one amount within the correct month and using it. I set up a tool tip for April so I could see what number it's pulling (since clearly the chart columns are not representing the data whatsoever - another issue).

[image: screenshot2]

You'll see in the SQL data screenshot that it does indeed pull $1,230 from the April 2013 Savings. How can I get this to Sum within the month AND still do a running value from the beginning of time data began to current, ***this often will include multiple years***.

Here's my Chart Data (note that my Team Goal works perfectly, and is even charted correctly - but if anyone knows how to force that line to go from end to end on my chart, feel free to let me know.) :

To summarize, how can I sum each month's data, while still do a running value across the months AND years?

Here's my Expression for Implementable Savings:

```
=RunningValue(Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value), Sum, nothing)
```

(obviously if I can get one working, I can get both)

My Expression for ImplementedSavingsMonth:

```
=MonthName(Month(Fields!ImplementedSavingsDate.Value))
```

My Expression for ImplementedSavingsYear:

```
=Year(Fields!ImplementedSavingsDate.Value)
```

Let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

Quick sidebar question: WHY does my chart column collect one piece of data. IE: see the tool tip $1,230 for April 2013), but the chart column displays that the number is around $1.7M? And in this scenario, both of my blue and yellow columns are displaying the same number, so why does blue always appear to be a higher number? I will ask this as a 2nd question if it's inappropriate for me to ask here.

Comment: Note, I tried to post a 3rd image link to show my chart data - but i can't because I don't have enough points. grrrr.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this Expression for Implementable Savings:

`= RunningValue ( Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, Sum, "Chart1")`

.. assuming your Chart's name is Chart1.